Going from a photon flux to a photon flux after a slit (partial photon flux)
Thanks to the help of someone here and others a few weeks ago (who referred me to the Jackson), I have managed to express the flux of a bending magnet like so:
$\frac{d_N}{\frac{d\omega}{\omega}} = \frac{I}{\hbar \omega_c^2} \omega \frac{9\sqrt{3}}{8 \pi} \int_{\frac{\omega}{\omega_c}}^{\infty} K_\frac{5}{3}(x)dx$
this is expressed in the units of $photons/second/0.1\%bw$
With a little python script, I can graph this as a function of the energy. To verify that the equation and code is correct I compare it with spectra (synchrotron sources software).
I end up with the same flux they do. All is good. I have normalised the fluxes.

When I select with Spectra the option partial flux which gives the user the option of adding a slit of a certain size at a certain distance from the source, I end up with a different flux (called partial photon flux).
First, I do not understand this.
I have both the angular divergence and the size of my beam at point $0$ (horizontal and vertical).
$beamsizeatD = 2D\tan \frac{\sigma'}{2}$ where D is the distance to the source and $\sigma'$ is the angular divergence (horizontal or vertical), I see that the beam should be smaller than the slit, therefore the slit shouldn't have an impact yet it does.
And even when I take into account the size of the beam $\sigma$ at point $0$:
$\sigma + 2D\tan \frac{\sigma'}{2}$
it's still smaller than the slit.
I have experimental data. When I use partial flux with Spectra taking into account the slit (as is done in real life) the calculation is very close to experimental data.

How can I take the slit into account for my calculation with the equation above?
Also, if I use a Monte Carlo ray tracing software, should anything be done other than the placement of a slit to get the partial flux?
Last remark that shows the slit is the reason for the change: when I use partial flux with Spectra and put a huge slit (as if there is none) then we go back to the flux of the above equation.
